# Encrypting a string 4

Tags: python

```
def main():
  inFile = open ('input.txt', 'r')
  fileContent = inFile.read()
  choice = input('Do you want to encrypt or decrypt? (E / D): ')
  for i in fileContent:
    if (choice == 'E'):
      for i in range(0, len(str), 2):
        even_str = str[i]
      for i in range(1, len(str), 2):
        odd_str = str[i]
      outFile = open("output.txt", "w")
      outFile.write(even_str)
      outFile.write(odd_str)
      outFile.write(encrypted_str)
      print('even_str = ',even_str)
      print('odd_string = ',odd_str)
      print('encrypted_str = ',encrypted_str)
      outfile.close()
    if (choice != 'E' and choice != 'D'):
      print ('')
      print ('Wrong input. Bye.')
      return
  inFile.close()
main()
```

Trying to encrypt a string and add the odd and even character together but I keep getting this error. I have a file set up to be tested but it appears to not be working.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/CS303E/Cipher.py", line 41, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Python33/CS303E/Cipher.py", line 24, in main
    for i in range(0, len(str), 2):
TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()
```

Answer (score 1):

You keep using `str` (the name of the type representing a string) when you should be using `fileContent` (the name of the variable containing your input string).

Answer (score 0):

`str` is a type (string, also you may think about it as about constructor), it's part of the language, and you don't have such variable. Maybe you want something like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(fileContent), 2):
```