# Encrypting a string 5

Tags: python

```
def main():
# open file to be used
  inFile = open ('input.txt', 'r')
  fileContent = inFile.readline()
  choice = input('Do you want to encrypt or decrypt? (E / D): ')
# find even and odd characters in string
  if (choice == 'E'):
      for i in range(0, len(fileContent), 2):
        even_str = fileContent[i]
      print(even_str)
      for i in range(1, len(fileContent), 2):
        odd_str = fileContent[i]
      encrypted_str = odd_str + even_str
# open outfile and write new strings in
      outFile = open("output.txt", "w")
      outFile.write(even_str)
      outFile.write(odd_str)
      outFile.write(encrypted_str)
      outFile.close()
  if (choice == 'D'):
      half = fileContent // 2
      even_str = fileContent[:half]
# return this if user has incorrect input
  if (choice != 'E' and choice != 'D'):
      print ('')
      print ('Wrong input. Bye.')
      return
  inFile.close()
main()
```

Right now I'm just testing to see what the output is for the even_str. The input is "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." and the output I keep getting for the even_str is "g" when I should be getting every even character.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypting a string 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876122/encrypting-a-string-4)

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning a new value to even_str each time through the loop, so when the loop is done the value will be whatever was last assigned--in this case 'g'. If you want a list of all the even characters, you need to make it a list and append each character to the list:

```
even_str = list()
for i in range(0, len(fileContent), 2):
    even_str.append(fileContent[i])
```